# How to send an email from Azure Databricks Scala Notebook

Tags: scala, azure-databricks

I have to send an email from azure databricks scala notebook. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SendGrid or Amazon-SES:

Here is the link to both the examples:

https://kb.databricks.com/notebooks/send-email.html

https://forums.databricks.com/questions/17785/databricks-sendgrid-integration.html